# Android 3 : Drag-and-Drop Views

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to use Android's new Drag&Drop framework and I run into the following issue:

- how can I pass Objects name in a DragEvent, so that it can be instantiated on ACTION_DROP?
- How can I pass a link to an existing Object(a View) so that it can be moved to a new place on ACTION_DROP?

I'm  operating inside of one single Activity, so Class Sources are available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented dragging and dropping a view, by introducing a DragHandler class with a variable

```
View isDraggedNow;
```

This Variable allwasy contains a dragged view, so every class can easily take it on DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED

Answer (score 1):

You could try a number of things. In my app, this is how i did it:

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v)
    {
    dragged_view = v;       
    removeTransition(v);

    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("path", ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.file_name)).getText());
    v.startDrag(data, new Shadow(v, c), v, 0);

    return true;
    }
```

I trigger the drag even on a long click gesture. I have a global `View` variable named `dragged_view` so that I can reference it on `ACTION_DROP`.

Another thing I did is pass the `View` as the [local state object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#startDrag%28android.content.ClipData,%20android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder,%20java.lang.Object,%20int%29) in the `startDrag()` method (it's the 3rd argument). I can then get it via `getLocalState()` and use it for reference, as in this code snippet:

```
item_drag_listener = new View.OnDragListener(){
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event){
            if (event.getLocalState() == v)
                return true;
            overlays = v.findViewById(R.id.copy_move_overlays);
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                    overlays.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                    overlays.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    return true;
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
            }
        };
```

Comment: this method works, because ClipData is able to pass text. How about passing complicated objects?